# Techniques for making a website more modular?

Tags: web, architecture

So I've written a basic web server in Node.js. It seems pretty inefficient to have to kill the server and re-run `node server.js` each time I want to add a new feature to my site.

What are the techniques for making a website more modular so I don't have to do this? How is this done in a larger scale, say, at very large website? I would like to be able to work on a small piece of the site without restarting the entire server, as it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some luck with [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) it reloads the server for you when you [hit the carriage return](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#manual-restarting).